# How to assign char values to an array using direct addressing

Tags: assembly, masm

A question came up today and I wasn't sure how to approach it.  Basically, we were given our data as

```
           .data
 alphabet   byte       0,0,0
```

and we needed swap the zeros for 'A', 'B', 'C'

```
            .data
  alphabet  byte    0,0,0

            .code
  Main proc

  mov alphabet, 'A'
  mov alphabet[1], 'B'
  mov alphabet[2], 'C'

  Main endp
  end
```

When debugging, alphabet is at the hex value of 0x41 'A'
How can I see what [1] and [2] are in the debugger?

Comment: _"Would this work?"_ Since you've already written some code, why not just try it and see if it works? For example, by inspecting it in a debugger or by adding some prints.

Comment: Sorry, I made my question more clear. I can get into the debugger, but alphabet is only showing 0x41 or 'A'.  How do I know if this is working for [1] and [2] of the array?

Comment: Presumably you're telling the debugger to show you `alphabet` as a single byte. If you tell it to show `alphabet` as a `DWORD` you would also see the next 3 bytes. Or maybe you can tell it to show you `alphabet+1` etc. Consult the manual of whatever debugger you're using.

Comment: Which debugger?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>           .data
> alphabet   byte       0,0,0
> ```

Without knowing about your debugger, you can always change the data layout in the next way:

```
          .data
alphabet   byte       0
EXTRA1     byte       0
EXTRA2     byte       0
```

Now look at the contents of EXTRA1 and EXTRA2 to see that they got 'B' and 'C'.

The instructions

```
mov alphabet, 'A'
mov alphabet[1], 'B'
mov alphabet[2], 'C'
```

will still work (`[1]` and `[2]` are just offsets to ALPHABET), as do

```
mov alphabet, 'A'
mov EXTRA1, 'B'
mov EXTRA2, 'C'
```